# Getting adb driver for htc wildfire so I can install my android apps

Tags: android

This is an android posting but I don't know how to correctly do the tags and the tags are not from a list so I am unsure if I have done the tag correctly.  Please advise me whether I have or not.

I set my htc wildfire setting for developer.  I plug it into my Windows 7 x64 laptop and it installs all but the adb driver.

I go here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

which advises me to go here:
developerandroidcom sdk oem-usbhtml

which advises me to go here:
htccom uk 
and to "Click on the support tab to select your products/device"

No 'tab' exists.  I navigate to products and select my product, I select the tab for downloads, I search all around but cannot find adb driver download.  After hours of searching I send a support request but get no reply.

I search for hours on google for htc wildfire adb drivers for win7 x64 but go round in circles for hours and get no where.

Long story short I have spent hours and hours getting started with android only to find that either I am too stupid or the installation to device process is too unsupported and I have wasted all that time and cannot ever put apps on my divice.

I would be grateful of any help any one i skind enough to give.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

as far as I know, almost all android devices share the same binary files of the adb driver. you could find it at {your-android-sdk-dir}/extras/google/usb_driver.zip. if not, open the *SDK manager* and check whether you've selected the installation of *Extras - Google USB Driver package*.

the only different is the *android_winusb.inf* file. open it and locate the *[Google.NTamd64]* section, you'll see settings like following (HTC Dream as an instance) for each devices:

```
; HTC Dream
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C02&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0FFF
```

the point is the VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx. for HTC wildfire, the settings might be as following:

```
;HTC Wildfire
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C8B
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C8B&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C94
```

to confirm the VID/PID settings, launch the windows device manager and locate the marfunctioned USB devices. just copy their VID/PID values and try in the .inf file....

note you may also have to create a file at the windows system's *Users/{your windows user}/.android/adb_usb.ini* and append following lines to it:

```
# HTC
0x0BB4
```

the value 0x0BB4 is the VID value you found in previous step.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can FINALLY use my wildfire again with the adb/eclipse. I didn't even have to do the last step (create a file at the windows systems *Users/....

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem with my HTC hero. I tried everything as you stated above (i.e. install USB driver in Android SDK, cmd, android_winusb.inf, etc) but my Eclipse and computer just cannot find the device. This is because you are missing the driver and those steps above won't do anything good if you dont have the driver installed. This driver is not the USB driver downloaded from SDK manager but the actual driver from the official website.

Here is how I finally solved the problem:

goto http://www.htc.com/us/support/, click **Phone** under I need help with. And choose your phone at the right side. Click software update at the bottom right corner. Click view more updates and then click ->> [HTC SYNC 3.0.5557 FOR HTC WILDFIRE S | 10.25.2011](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-wildfire-s-vmobile/software-updates) Then download the SYNC software. Open the software and then the software will run a script to detect if you have the driver installed on your computer. If not, SYNC will install the phone driver for you. When the software finished installing driver, you should be able to put your app on your device.

Comment: The link now leads to the HTC one and the HTC Sync softer does not list the Wildfire as far as I can see.

Comment: I found a download link for HTC Sync: http://dl4.htc.com/managed-assets/support/software/htc-sync/htc_sync_setup_3.3.21.exe, on the Dutch support site for Wildfire S: http://www.htc.com/nl/support/news.aspx?p_id=392&p_name=htc-wildfire-s.